# Setting Videotitel via useState in React native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a dynamically generated video view in React native. I call the side `Play` with the parameters `letter` and `mode`. The selected video found out of an array is correct. See console log. But the `videoTitel` itself is always the video from the first side call. So it's not updating when I call the side again. The title only changes if I change `setVideoTitle`, e.g., with a button `onclick`.

```js
export default function Play ({ navigation, route}) {

let letter = route.params.Letter;
let mode = route.params.Mode;

const video = useRef(null);
const [selection, setSelection] = useState(0);

const Videos = require('../components/Videos');
const selectedVideo = Videos.Array.find(V => V.name === letter.toString());
console.log(selectedVideo)
const [videoTitel, setVideoTitel] = useState(selectedVideo.Front[mode]);
console.log("VideoTitel: "+ videoTitel)
const [videoSpeed, setVideoSpeed] = useState(1.0);
```

[image]

Comment: Hey dude! Next time try to send the full component and also how it's used, so people could understand more the problem, and also you might get code suggestions if you do that! Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you are using this Play function but try this:

```js
const Videos = require('../components/Videos');

function Play ({ navigation, route }) {
const video = useRef(null);
let letter = route.params.Letter;
let mode = route.params.Mode;

const [selection, setSelection] = useState(0);
const [videoSpeed, setVideoSpeed] = useState(1);
const [videoTitel, setVideoTitel] = useState();
const selectedVideo = Videos.Array.find(V => V.name === letter.toString());

useEffect(() => {
  if(selectedVideo && mode) {
    setVideoTitle(selectedVideo.Front[mode]);
    console.log('Selected Video:', selectedVideo);
    console.log('VideoTitel: ', videoTitel);
  }
},[selectedVideo, mode]);

...
};

export default Play;
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. But i already tried to set the video title in the useEffect function. But in my try the useEffect function just called once. The first time i switched to the side. Why is that always be called?

Comment: Ah it`s because the parameter inside [] if selectedVideo or mode changed useEffect will be called

Comment: Yes, you should read React useEffect and useState usage, you will understand more on how to handle them correctly. Is very important to read the documentation because you might trigger several app state changes and that could be a problem.